# Can you create an Android testing app that runs atop of other specified android apps?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, automated-tests

I'm trying to build an android application that essentially is able to scrape other apps to simulate a user for UI testing. Is this something that is possible? The technologies I'm using are Android Studio, Java, and UI Automator. I've done some research, but I haven't found anything that seems to directly confirm or deny that it's possible thus far. My strategy is thus:

- Start up application and grab all installed packages
- Via a SearchView allow the tester to narrow their search and pick from the ListView
- Then grab the packageName to launch the app via a new intent
- Have user pick what tests to run (i.e. a view finder and log their ids into to LogCat to show that it is rendering correctly)

I'm asking mainly to see if my strategy is either viable with either what technology I'm currently working with like UI Automator, my current strategy, or if it's viable at all due to Android OS' architecture

Comment: UI Automator needs to be run from test suites (e.g., JUnit). It cannot be used from an ordinary Android app. Beyond that, you are welcome to use accessibility APIs, subject to their security and distribution limitations.

Comment: @CommonsWare Would it be possible to programmatically run the tests similar to what is done here? [Running JUnit Tests Programmatically, from a Java Application](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java) Are there any accessibility APIs you would recommend I look into?

Comment: "Would it be possible to programmatically run the tests similar to what is done here?" -- not really. In particular, you will not have the permissions necessary to use UI Automator that way. "Are there any accessibility APIs you would recommend I look into?" -- probably all of them. 